# JavaScript for moving text not working

Tags: javascript

I have written a simple JavaScript code for moving text, but when I run the program nothing happens.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function move() {
        divElement = document.getElementById("MovingContent");             
        divElement.style.left = parseInt(divElement.style.left)+1+"px";         
        setInterval('move()', 1000);          
    }

    window.onload=move 

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body style="background-color:#303030" onload="move()">
<asp:Label ForeColor="#2A4191" ID="MovingContent" text="Good Morning" runat="server" style="position:absolute;display:block;" >
</asp:Label>
```

Comment: can you please add your html or provide fiddle ?

Comment: the call of your function in setInterval should be done like this setInterval(move, 1000).

Comment: @JordanWD passing a string instead of a function still works with `setInterval`, it uses eval internally if passed a string

Comment: You have HTML tags in your JavaScript. Too much React cool aid?

Comment: Is it because of all the `<br/>` inside the code? Are those in your actual code too?

Comment: @juhana & Pavlo No. </br> is not in code.

Comment: @SethuRaman check my answer i have added code  remove onload="move()" as you already use window.onload=move.

Comment: call setInterval('move()', 1000); inside window.onload as i mention in my answer

Comment: @SethuRaman, if `script` is placed inside `<body>` or `<head>`, everything should work fine. There is no needs to change your code.

Comment: @SethuRaman i have added demo with `label` tag . you need wrap text using any HTML tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code    check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/46p00q66/)  . you can call `setInterval` inside  `window.onload` function

remove all `<br/>` from javascript code . property of css `left` work with `position:absolute` or `position:relative` to then element.

UPDATE : i add HTML as you post in comment . have added left:0px to  MovingContent and remove  onload="move()" as already use this in javascript

Check [DEOM](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/46p00q66/2/)

HTML

```
 <body style="background-color:#303030" >
   <asp:Label ForeColor="#2A4191" ID="MovingContent" text="Good Morning" runat="server" style="position:absolute;display:block;left:0px" ></asp:Label> 
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
 function move() {
    divElement = document.getElementById("MovingContent");               
    divElement.style.left = parseInt(divElement.style.left)+1+"px";          
}

window.onload= function(){
 setInterval('move()', 1000);
} 
</script>
```

```js
function move() {
        divElement = document.getElementById("MovingContent");               
        divElement.style.left = parseInt(divElement.style.left)+1+"px";          
    }

window.onload= function(){
  setInterval('move()', 1000);
 }
```

```html
<label style="left:0px;position:absolute;" id="MovingContent"> moving data </label>
```

Comment: Working code itself isn't as useful as the knowledge how to write working code.

Comment: @Pavlo i already mention you can call setInterval inside  window.onload function to my answer . this will work for him .. nothing wrong in other code

Comment: The thing is that this is not much different than the code in the question. If you try the original code it works too so it's not helpful to give something only slightly different if the actual cause of the problem is unclear. See ahmed's answer: the likely problem is that the element doesn't have inline styles set so you can't access the `.style.left` property the first time around. (Notice how your code doesn't work with the OP's HTML (in a comment to the question): http://jsfiddle.net/46p00q66/3/)

Comment: Yes, I know what the problem is. You didn't understand the point I was trying to make.

Answer (score 1):

this is a fixed version of your code:

```
function move() {
    divElement = document.getElementById("MovingContent");
    divElement.style.left = (parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(divElement)['left'])+1)+ "px";
}

window.onload= function(){
    setInterval(function(){move();}, 500);
}
```

use "window.getComputedStyle(divElement)" to get the left value.

Answer (score -1):

I have created a fiddle, check it out below

https://jsfiddle.net/512baL7k/6/

Assuming element with id as **MovingContent**, as follows

```
<div id="MovingContent" style="background: red; height: 10px; width: 10px; left: 1px; position: relative;" />
```

**EDIT** Looks like code was not saved. I have updated fiddle

Comment: what is difference b/w absolute and relative positioning

Comment: Check this [Link](http://www.cssreset.com/understanding-css-relative-and-absolute-positioning-explained/)